# In BIRT how to change the default time range into week base

Tags: java, report, birt

I meet a problem that I have two parameters, the start date and end date. I want the default date automatically change into week base. For example, today is may 24, so the default start date should be may 17, and the default end date should be today, and then tomorrow the default value of date would automatically change. How can I do that, can anyone help me?

Response would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute the first day of the current week in default value expressions of report parameters. For example:

*BirtDateTime.firstDayOfWeek(BirtDateTime.today())*

A simple report example using this kind of "BirtDateTime" expressions and default values [here](http://www.visioneo.org/week-parameters)

**EDIT:**

In order to extract 7-last-days we can set a such expression for default value of StartDate parameter:

*BirtDateTime.addDay(BirtDateTime.today(),-7)*

Comment: Thank you for your help, I used that way before. But it just set the first day of this week as the start date, and today as the end date. What I want is to fix the time range into 7 days. For example today is May 26, so the start date should be 7 days before May 26, May 19, and the end date is today, and then tomorrow the start date can be automatically changed from May 19 to May 20, etc. Could you tell me how to do that.

Comment: Ok i had been confused by "week base" requirement. To substract days in  a BIRT expression, a simple approach is to add a negative number of days, i edited the answer.

Comment: And can you help answer my another question? The question with the title named "In BIRT how to see different master-page with different parameter that user selected"